# Remove element with a specific value from an array

Tags: arrays, c

i would like to remove an int from my int array. however, the item cannot be remove and its replaced by "0" instead. I search some code online and they only show example of remove the POSITION of the array.. but here i am removing the value of the variable. my code shown below

Data in array (Insert method)

**5 6 7 8 10 1 2 3 4**

Test case (Delete method)

**Enter integer to be remove : 7**

Display Array (Display method)

**5 6 8 10 1 2 3 4**

```
void iremove (int *size, int ar[], int num)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<*size;i++)
    {
        if(ar[i]==num)
        {
            ar[i]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting the element to 0, you need to loop through the remaining elements, moving them each up by one.  Then update the size.

Comment: any website i can reference this to?

Comment: Found this by googling "c delete array element": https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-delete-element-from-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It is already mentioned in the comments though.

```
void iremove(int *size, int a[], int num)
{
    int idx, i;
    for(i=0; i<*size; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == num)
        {
            idx = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i == *size)
    {
        printf("No such element found!\n");
        return;
    }

    for(i=idx+1; i<*size; i++)
    {
        a[i-1] = a[i];
    }

    (*size)--;
    return;
}
```

It first finds the index and then shifts the rest of the array, from `idx + 1` one position to the left. Also decrements the `size` of the original array.

Comment: **Warning:** in case the element is not found this finction results in undefined behavior, as `idx` isn't initialized! Please, correct it. **Hint:** initialize it to -1 and check for `idx != -1` before swapping. Otherwise just initialize to `*size`. (A null pointer check to `size` would also make the function safer)

Comment: But in case the element is not found, the function returns straightaway by checking `i` and not `idx`. I guess there won't be any runtime issue.

Comment: its not working, it keep saying "no such element found". But the thing is i wanna remove by the value and not the position to remove

Comment: There was an order mismatch from your function and my function in passing arguments. I fixed it, now it should work if you call as `iremove(&size, ar, num)`. Check and do let me know.

Comment: hm, for my requirements, the method should have this args

`void iremove(int *size, int ar[], int num);` can i take in an `int ar[]` instead of `int * a`?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed it earlier. Hope it works now!

Comment: Yes, you can take in `int ar[]` instead of my `int* a`. Changed it anyway now.

Comment: I probably commented the first version of the code. A null pointer check to size would still make the function safer

Comment: @swag2198 nice. its all working great.. i tried adding this at the first portion of remove,
`if(*size==-1)
 { printf("The array is empty\n"); }`
 is this the right way to check empty?

Comment: No, if the array is empty, it's length will be zero, so a check of `if (*size == 0)` should work. Also if you pass a NULL pointer as size, then you have to check `if(size == NULL)`. Depends on what and how you store the size variable from outside in case the array is empty.

Comment: @swag2198 thanks! all is good now! much appreciated